# Eclipse Kepler SR2 is sluggish on Linux while editing large source files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

I've Eclipse Kepler SR2 on SUSE Linux server which has the below components:

C/C++ Development Tools (CDT) - 8.3
Rational Clearcase plug-ins - 7.6.2.v201309301552
JRE 1.6.0_45

I'm using the vmargs as below:
-vmargs -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m

I'm trying to launch Kepler SR2 with the Juno workspace. But the first time launch took nearly 15mins.Why it took that much time even though my -vm settings are pretty good? From the second launch onwards, it took below 20 secs.

Even after the launch, when I try to edit the C/C++ source files, Kepler is responding very slow. Even a single click on the variables, taking 20 to 30 sec time to highlight the variable. This is happening only to the source files which has huge file size(nearly 1MB) and when the content is still not saved. No performance issues with the smaller files.The used heap is fluctuating between 300MB and 1100MB.

Found another scenario: Kepler is sluggish when we switch between editors and placing the cursor on the variables. Hover doesn't display the popup at all, single click doesn't highlight the variables for nearly 50 to 60 sec, also double click doesn't select the variable for nearly 50 to 60 sec.

How to solve the sluggish behavior?

Comment: Have you got scalability mode enabled? Under C/C++ > Editor > Scalability. You can set a few different options under there, including the minimum file length to trigger it.

Comment: Yes, when the number of lines in the file is more than 999999

Comment: Set the limit to 99999 since I've 40K+ lines in few source files. Same result. Very slow response. This time it took more than 30sec.

Comment: So just to clarify - you're continuing to see performance issues on files where scalability mode has kicked in? Is this in all interactions with the file - e.g. scrolling, typing - or only on highlighting variables? 100k lines still seems a high limit to me.

Comment: My answer is 'No' for your first question. My file size is 40K. I set the scalability to 50K.So no popup displayed when I open the 40K size file.  No issues with scrolling, typing, double clicks on the variables. The problem is with only single-clicks for all the users.

Comment: Hm, weird. My only other suggestion would be to try disabling code folding, which has sometimes improved performance for me in the past, but I had issues with other actions then, not just single clicks.

Comment: When we switch from one source file to another, double clicks on the variables are also taking longer times to highlight the variables. This can be consistently reproducible when the file modifications are not yet saved.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues with cdt and disabling indexing helped to some extent. Several performance problems seem to exist in cdt indexing when large files are involved. Try to disable indexing and see if it makes a difference